# Pushing keys and values into a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am parsing lines of code that look like `Key: Value`, and am inserting the `Key` and `Value` elements into an array. Then I'm iterating through that array and attempting to store these values into a hash. I want it to be like: `"Host => "localhost"` and `"Content-Length" => "17"`.

I tried to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034262/how-to-push-keys-and-values-into-an-empty-hash-w-ruby):

```
def parse_headers
@headers = {}
  while ! (line = next_line).empty?
header_elements = line.split(': ')
header_elements.each do |key, val|
    @headers[key] = val
end
    parse_header(line)
  end
puts @headers
end
```

I think my syntax is wrong. When I print the hash, there are only keys, and all values are `nil`.

[image: output]

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should pay attention to proper indentation of your code. Otherwise really simple pieces will get really messy really soon. You're basically inflicting pain on yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice that your resulting hash also contains keys which should be values? That's because `header_elements` is an array and you're trying to iterate it as a hash (which it isn't). In fact, you don't need to iterate it.

```
key, val = line.split(': ')
@headers[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is the same as Sergio's answer, but you don't have to use two variables for it. And for safeness, you can add an argument `2`.

```
@headers.store(*line.split(': ', 2))
```